# 'str' object has no attribute 'weekday' Convert date to a string

Tags: python, string, datetime, outlook

I am trying to send an Outlook email with a small table in the body that is taken from an Excel. The subject of the email should have last working date's (Monday through Friday) in yyyy-mm- day format. I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'weekday'.

Anybody can help me with the date format for the email? Thanks!

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_excel("Name of file","Name of tab", index_col=0, nrows = 2,  usecols = "B:E")
df.rename({"Unnamed: 4":" "}, axis="columns", inplace=True)
body = df.to_html() 


date = str (datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
shift = datetime.timedelta(max(1,(date.weekday()+6)%7 - 3))

outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
new_mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
new_mail.To = 'abcdefgh@outlook.com'
new_mail.Subject = 'XXXXXXX as of ' + str (date - shift)
new_mail.HTMLBody = (body)
new_mail.Send()
```

Comment: You have converted datetime object to string in date = str (datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')). Remove str() and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date = datetime.datetime.today()
shift = datetime.timedelta(max(1,(date.weekday()+6)%7 - 3))
...

new_mail.Subject = 'XXXXXXX as of ' + (date - shift).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

The problem is that you convert date to string initially and therefore cannot perform date arithmetic on it from there on.